# Filtering tabular data by using scrapy pipeline

Tags: python, scrapy

I've scrapped the tabular data i want from a page. Now I want to filter them ('Version' only) using a pipeline:

The web data is available here:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/visual-studio-build-numbers-and-release-dates?view=vs-2022

'''

```
    from scrapy.exceptions import DropItem


    class ScrapytestPipeline:



       def process_item(self, item, spider):

          if item['Channel'] == 'Release':
             return item
          else:
             raise DropItem("Missing specified keywords.")'''
```

Problem is its returning nothing now.

The spider:

```
   import scrapy
   from ..items import ScrapytestItem
   class VsCodeSpider(scrapy.Spider):
      name = 'vscode'
      start_urls = [
       'https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/visual-studio-build-numbers-and- 
        release-dates?view=vs-2022'
       ]

      def parse(self, response):
          item = ScrapytestItem()
          products =  response.xpath('//table/tbody//tr')

          for i in products:
             item = dict()

             item['Version'] = i.xpath('td[1]//text()').extract()
             item['Channel'] = i.xpath('td[2]//text()').extract()
             item['Releasedate'] = i.xpath('td[3]//text()').extract()
             item['Buildversion'] = i.xpath('td[4]//text()').extract()

             yield item
```

The items.py file:

```
import scrapy


class ScrapytestItem(scrapy.Item):
    Version = scrapy.Field()
    Channel = scrapy.Field()
    Releasedate = scrapy.Field()
    Buildversion = scrapy.Field()
```

How can I filter (only 'Version' values in the 'Channel' Field) using the pipeline? Thanks!

Comment: Yes, trying it on pycharm CLI

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by (only version values in the channel field)

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing in the code is packing all these things in a dictionary and yielding the dictionary.

However, What I understand from your question is that you need to filter values for versions or channel field.(correct me if I am wrong). I recommend you yield them separately. As shown in the code below, to achieve the desired results.

```
 def parse(self, response):
          item = ScrapytestItem()
          products =  response.xpath('//table/tbody//tr')

          for i in products:
      

             Version = i.xpath('td[1]//text()').extract()
             Channel = i.xpath('td[2]//text()').extract()
             Releasedate = i.xpath('td[3]//text()').extract()
             Buildversion = i.xpath('td[4]//text()').extract()

             yield { "Version":Version, "Channel": Channel,"Releasedate":Releasedate, "Buildversion":Buildversion }
```

This way you can filter data using the pipeline. Also, I recommend looking at the itemloaders.  They will help create even more sophisticated Data pipelines. You read about them [here](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/loaders.html) or watch [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wyE4oDxScfE) or read [this blog](https://towardsdatascience.com/demystifying-scrapy-item-loaders-ffbc119d592a).

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are using `extract` instead of  `extract_first`.

When you use `extract`, it extracts all the items and returns a list of strings. If you run this spider, you will see `[]` in the output:

```
{'Version': ['16.0.1'], 'Channel': ['Preview 1'], 'Releasedate': ['April 9, 2019'], 'Buildversion': ['16.0.28803.156']}
```

You are dropping everything which does not equal a string, and your results are a list.

To fix it, change `extract` to `extract_first`

This is a common error, and thus it is recommended to use the `get` and `getall` methods, which are more obvious.

TLDR; Use `get` if you want a string, `getall` when you want a list. Also, stop using `extract` for better readability.